# Display print messages in console PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm using PyInstaller to convert my Python file to .exe; however, I see that upon running the executable file, I don't see any print messages in the terminal which I use for my reference - it's just blank (no print messages).

Command I used: `pyinstaller --onefile -w myfile.py`

I use Selenium module in my Python file, which uses chromedriver.exe, so after running the generated .exe file, this is what it shows:

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

from time import sleep
import random

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

print("Opened the browser")
```

Pictures:

[image]
[image]

I need to see the print messages. Tried searching for answers but couldn't find any solutions!

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Basically, I use Selenium module in my Python script, which uses chromedriver.exe - so I only see a console window that displays chromedriver messages, like "listening" and others, but NOT the print messages I coded, which should appear in terminal.

Comment: Yes, I ran .exe, and my code runs, the console opens but it doesn't display print messages there.

Comment: And _how_ are you running your `.exe`? Are you doing that from a terminal like PowerShell or cmd.exe?

Comment: My question clearly states I ran the .exe file. " however, I see that upon running the executable file,"

I'll provide a screenshot: https://paste.pics/3c2f077fa9629f5f97f9208a1ad317f1

Comment: I edited my question. Well, I don't see print messages... what am I doing wrong? 

EDIT: Okay, editing my question and providing the code.

Comment: Great, thanks. _How_ are you running the generated `.exe`? From PowerShell or cmd.exe? Or by double-clicking it?

Comment: Just by clicking on the .exe file like running any normal file in the Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your `.exe` from a terminal like PowerShell it will probably show the output you're looking for. The window in the screenshot looks like it is coming from the Selenium driver.

If you want this to work when double-clicking on the `.exe`, rebuild without [the `-w` flag](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-w):

> `-w, --windowed, --noconsole`
>
> Windows and Mac OS X: do not provide a console window for standard i/o. On Mac OS this also triggers building a Mac OS .app bundle. On Windows this option is automatically set if the first script is a ‘.pyw’ file. This option is ignored on *NIX systems.

Comment: Thank you! Can you provide me a full command line? I'm a little confused what to include after the pyinstaller line.

Comment: @Cassano, well it depends on what you want to do :-). But based on what you show in your question, try `pyinstaller --onefile myfile.py`.

Comment: It worked! I appreciate you tons. And I'll definitely ask the question properly next time.

Comment: Great! Sorry for being such a pain, but I believe the question is now a lot clearer and more likely to help other users in the future. Thanks for sticking with it!